# python3 - how to produce output files whose names are modifications of the input files names?

Tags: python, glob, biopython

Hello I'm using a python script that consist in the following code:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
 
# set input file, output file to write to 

gbk_file = "bin.10.gbk"
tsv_file = "results.bin_10.tsv"
cluster_out = open(tsv_file, "w")


# Extract CLuster info. write to file 

for seq_record in SeqIO.parse(gbk_file, "genbank"):
    for seq_feat in seq_record.features:
        if seq_feat.type == "protocluster":
            cluster_number = seq_feat.qualifiers["protocluster_number"][0].replace(" ","_").replace(":","")
            cluster_type = seq_feat.qualifiers["product"][0]
            cluster_out.write("#"+cluster_number+"\tCluster Type:"+cluster_type+"\n")
```

THe issue is that I want to automatize this script to multiple files in a certain directory, in this way I want that `gbk_file` stores all the files that have .gbk as suffix, and that `tsv_file` results in a respective output file according to each input file.

so if a input file has the name "bin.10.gbk", the output will be "results.bin_10.tsv".

I tried using glob python function but dont know how to create a `tsv_file` variable that stores modified strings from imput file names:

```
  import glob
    # setting variables
    gbk_files = glob.glob("*.gbk")
    tsv_files = gbk_files.replace(".gbk",".results.tsv")
    cluster_out = open(tsv_files, "w")
```

making that changes, I got the following error:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

so how can I deal with this?

Thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 0):

Hope the following function can help you.

```
def processfiles():
    for file in glob.glob("*.gbk"):
        names = file.split('.')
        tsv_file = f'results.{names[-3]}_{names[-2]}.tsv'
        with open(tsv_file, 'w') as tsv:
            tsv.write('write your content here')
            tsv.close
```

Comment: in that way I should enter the for loops  described in "# Extract CLuster info. write to file" into tsv.write() ?